# Libraries to work with Unicode in C?

Tags: open-source, library, c, unicode

I'm currently using `char *` for strings in my C program. I'd like to learn how to implement Unicode support and have been looking at `utf8proc`.

Is `utf8proc` the best general-purpose Unicode library for C? Other than the documentation in the header file, are there examples for its use?

For instance, I can figure out how to compile `utf8proc` into my codebase, but other than that, I'm at a loss — do I keep using `char *` or do I use some other type? Stuff like that is not well described.

If there are better libraries or better-documented libraries, what should I be looking at?

Comment: What functionality are you looking for? Splitting UTF-8 into characters? into glyphs? Converting between representations? Character classes (e.g. figuring out what's whitespace)? …

Comment: If you want to handle *all* of Unicode, you will need to look for a UTF-16 library, not UTF-8.

Comment: I want to let users stream a data matrix with labeled rows and columns (potentially containing Unicode characters) into my program, and my program processes that data matrix into an internal data store. My program then processes that data store and renders it into an SVG file, which may contain Unicode-formatted strings placed at specific locations. So I want to know how to support reading and writing those kinds of strings. I can deal with ASCII because `(unsigned) char *` does that for me. I want to be able to support non-ASCII-speaking users, however. Does that help clear things up?

Comment: These days GLib has excellent unicode support.

Answer (score 1):

Not a library as such, but I wrote some UTF-8 functions for my own C projects, which you can find [here](https://gitlab.com/gobusto/vector/tree/master/v2dx/xml) in the `unicode.h` and `unicode.c` files. They use the [MIT licence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_license) so you can basically do whatever you want with them.